# Getting ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when trying to access in Chrome my FastAPI server in a Docker container

Tags: docker, networking, fastapi

I used fastapi for my project as a simple server. On local host it works, but I have problems putting it publicly available on my IP.
I followed the official tutorial at https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker
and then ran a docker container successfully (this worked`sudo docker run -d --name mycontainer -p 80:80 myimage`. But it was not on a public IP.
So i tried:

```
sudo docker network create --subnet 172.20.0.0/16 --ip-range 172.20.240.0/20 multi-host-network
sudo docker network connect --ip 172.20.128.2 multi-host-network /mycontainer
```

But when I try to access it from 4G on my phone, it gives a timeout.
Although the 4G network is fast.
I am a newbie in webservers, so please don't judge me :)
If you want me to write more, just ask me, I will. If you want, I will upload my FastAPI server code and my client code as well.
My system is Linux Mint 20.2
Thanks for your help!

Comment: `172.20.x` is a private ip range; it is not available or routed on the general internet. You need to get your actual external ip and route the request to your server through every network layer (router/ingress/etc).

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks, but when I found my IP with curl checkip.dyndns.org, and sudo docker network connect --ip 93.153.49.187 multi-host-network mycontainer, a router page pops up. What do I do?

Comment: You need to route the request from your router to the server you're running docker on - this is usually done through a port forward. You need the ip of your server on the internal network. You then attach docker to your internal network IP (the IP that the request has been port forwarded to) and can serve requests that way. The point is that the router sees the request from the internet on the given port, and knows that the request shall be forwarded to a specific internal host. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding

Comment: @MatsLindh I'm totally new to this stuff, sorry. Could you please guide me?

Comment: There is plenty of tutorials on the internet if you search for port forwarding guide - you can also use the name of your specific router to probably get a step-by-step guide for your exact brand of router.